# Only one app error: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

There's a app can runs in the simulator, but doesn't work in the device. My Xcode version is 5.0.2, and OS X version is 10.9.1. There's the error log:

> CodeSign /Users/luke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eRep-hfteeueqsdstlddzcfobqwmsgsio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/eRep.app
>       cd /Users/luke/CoreProgram/eRep_svn_Code/eRep
>       setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       Using code signing identity "iPhone Developer: Zhenghong Zhu (XXX....)" and provisioning profile "LuDevelopment" (XXX....)
>       codesign --force --sign XXX.... --resource-rules=/Users/luke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eRep-hfteeueqsdstlddzcfobqwmsgsio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/eRep.app/ResourceRules.plist - ObjC -all_load --entitlements /Users/luke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eRep-hfteeueqsdstlddzcfobqwmsgsio/Build/Intermediates/eRep.build/Debug-iphoneos/eRep.build/eRep.xcent /Users/luke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eRep-hfteeueqsdstlddzcfobqwmsgsio/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/eRep.app
>   ll_load: unknown architecture name
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
>
> ll_load: unknown architecture name
>
> Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

There has no same certificate in the Keychain Access.I built a new app, it can runs in the device with the same certificate. I don't know why only this app doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I built a new project, and copied all resources to it. The new project can runs on the device.

Comment: Refreshing worked for me. Xcode 6.

Comment: This is down to a corrupt framework or asset file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unknown architecture name` this is the problem, check your project setting about architecture, or the debug target setting.

Comment: Thanks. I found the reason. I ought to add flags "-ObjC" and "-all_load" to the "Other Linker Flags", but I made a mistake. I added them to the "Other Code Signing Flags".

Comment: Congratulations! Sorry for that I didn't point out the problem directly.`- ObjC -all_load --entitlements` is also the information for error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your device's UDID to the provisioning profile via the iOS Dev Center?

Comment: Sure. Other apps can run on this device.

Comment: Make sure you don't have multiple development distribution profiles with similar names but different expiration dates in your keychain and in your developer account.  Xcode gets confused.  Also, try going to Preferences > Accounts > select your team > View Details > click the refresh button in the bottom left to make sure your certificates are up to date.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to refresh the Account setting in Xcode, and checked profiles with developer account. Xcode shows the same error.